# DevExpress DateEdit Force user to use menu popup

Tags: winforms, datepicker, devexpress

I have a WinForms app that uses this control and I would like to prevent the user from typing in a date.  We want to make them have to use the popup calendar to make the date selection.

I tried setting ReadOnly of course but that puts the whole control into the read only state.

Our version of DevExpress is: 9.1.9.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this task using the [RepositoryItemButtonEdit.TextEditStyle](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemButtonEdit_TextEditStyletopic) property.
Assign the `DisableTextEditor`value with this property. In this mode a button editor is displayed in its normal way. However, editing and selecting text is not allowed.

Code snippet:

```
dateEdit1.Properties.TextEditStyle = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.TextEditStyles.DisableTextEditor;
```